# How can I select an option in html based on the values I already have in SQL?

Tags: python, html, flask

#### Scenario:

I'm working on a school project in flask. It should enable someone to create a character by selecting options from a drop down list and occasionally manually entering values. I've got it set up so the selections are saved in a database, but they need to be able to access and edit them again, and the same user may have multiple characters, so I can't just hard-code it in. I think the best way to do this is to display the same selection page they created the character with, but with the options they chose already selected and the data they entered in its correct place.

#### Problem:

I just don't know how I would get the html to display the needed values, both in the drop down menus and the text entries. I haven't started the flask side as I'm genuinely clueless as to where to start, but this is what I currently have on the html side:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Character sheet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />
</head>
<body>
    <span><div style="background-color:white;color:black;padding:10px;"></span>
        <h4>Character Sheet</h4>
        <form action='/sheet', method="POST">
            <input type='submit' name='update'>
       <p>Name:<input name="character name" type="text">
        <span>Class: <select name='class'></span>
            <option value='C'>Cleric</option>
            <option value='R'>Ranger</option>
            </select>
        <span>Race: <select name='race'> </span>
            <option value='H'>Human</option>
            <option value='T'>Tiefling</option>
            <option value='O'>Half-Orc</option>
            </select>
        <span>Level: <select name='level'></span>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
        </select>
        </form></p>
        <p>{{errors}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance and I hope this is enough information, but let me know if I missed something :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send back the data from the call to the template and a for loop

```
<span>Level: <select name='level'></span>
{% for item in items %}
<option value='{{item.id}}'>{{item.value}}</option>
{%endfor%}
</select>
```